# Check whether column value is in another column which values is a list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two columns in a dataframe. The first one contains a string in each row. The second contains a set of strings for each row. How can i check, for each row, whether the value from the first column is in the set of the second using pandas functions and that its efficient?

pd.DataFrame([np.random.randint(5, size=12), np.random.randint(5, size=(12,5))]).T

[image]

How to check if the value from column 0 in the list of column 1

Answer (score 10):

with a list comprehension and `zip` (IMO this will be faster than `apply`):

```
df=df.assign(Check=[a in b for a,b in zip(df[0],df[1])])
```

---

```
    0                1  Check
0   4  [4, 4, 2, 3, 0]   True
1   4  [1, 0, 2, 1, 4]   True
2   0  [2, 1, 1, 2, 2]  False
3   0  [0, 3, 3, 2, 3]   True
4   4  [3, 0, 0, 3, 1]  False
5   1  [0, 2, 0, 3, 4]  False
6   0  [4, 3, 4, 1, 1]  False
7   1  [2, 0, 0, 3, 1]   True
8   2  [3, 3, 3, 2, 4]   True
9   2  [3, 0, 0, 4, 1]  False
10  0  [3, 3, 3, 4, 3]  False
11  1  [0, 3, 3, 2, 1]   True
```

*Performance* on the test data:

[image]

Comment: Wow, nice one! :)

Comment: BTW would like share the data ?

Comment: @WeNYoBen which one? the testable fragment ? `df=pd.DataFrame([np.random.randint(5, size=12), np.random.randint(5, size=(12,5))]).T`

Comment: @anky_91 thank you :-) would you like addig the timing of isin ?

Comment: @WeNYoBen done. dataframe constructor outperforms apply as expected, but lit comp with zip works nicely here :)

Comment: @anky_91: Nice one. I never expect listcomp faster than pandas df construction and `isin` that much! :) +1

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, given, for example:

```
   Col1       Col2
0     0  [0, 1, 2]
1     1  [2, 3, 4]
2     2  [4, 5, 2]
```

You can do:

```
df['Result'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.Col1 in x.Col2, axis = 1)
```

Output:

```
   Col1       Col2  Result
0     0  [0, 1, 2]    True
1     1  [2, 3, 4]   False
2     2  [4, 5, 2]    True
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC `isin`

```
pd.DataFrame(df[1].values.tolist(),index=df.index).isin(df[0]).any(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy broadcasting and `any`

Sample as:

```
df:    
Out[429]:
    0                1
0   1  [0, 2, 2, 2, 0]
1   0  [0, 4, 3, 2, 4]
2   4  [4, 1, 0, 3, 2]
3   4  [1, 0, 1, 4, 1]
4   0  [3, 3, 1, 2, 2]
5   4  [0, 4, 2, 2, 0]
6   1  [2, 1, 1, 1, 0]
7   4  [0, 4, 2, 4, 0]
8   0  [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
9   0  [4, 2, 3, 3, 1]
10  2  [0, 4, 2, 3, 2]
11  3  [1, 3, 2, 2, 1]

df['Flag_isin'] = (df[0].values[:, None] == np.vstack(df[1].values)).any(1)

Out[431]:
    0                1  Flag_isin
0   1  [0, 2, 2, 2, 0]      False
1   0  [0, 4, 3, 2, 4]       True
2   4  [4, 1, 0, 3, 2]       True
3   4  [1, 0, 1, 4, 1]       True
4   0  [3, 3, 1, 2, 2]      False
5   4  [0, 4, 2, 2, 0]       True
6   1  [2, 1, 1, 1, 0]       True
7   4  [0, 4, 2, 4, 0]       True
8   0  [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]      False
9   0  [4, 2, 3, 3, 1]      False
10  2  [0, 4, 2, 3, 2]       True
11  3  [1, 3, 2, 2, 1]       True
```